# NodeJS after sending request and set interval to repeat the function, I update my code source, but the code source response for my code not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am sending a request with Node.js to get code source of a website and setting interval of 5 seconds, and then I am changing my code source in my server, but the code still getting the old code source, it's not updating, here is the code

```
const request = require('request');
setInterval(() => {
        request('https://example.com/', function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
    });
}, 5000);
```

after I change something in my source code, the console not updating

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying that you update the page on the target `https://example.com` and this code doesn't get the new updated page?  Or are you updating something in your local nodejs program?  Do you restart your nodejs server after changing your nodejs source code?  Do you restart the target server after updating it's page?  The target server may be doing some internal caching?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am changing the code source on the target, but the script still retrieving old code source

Comment: The target server probably has internal caching.